# Extract object.keys from boolean dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, underscore.js

I'm using js & underscore.js, how can I transform the following boolean dictionary:

```
{first: true, second: false, third: true}
```

to the following key array:

```
['first', 'third']
```

Comment: `var arr = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(e) {return obj[e];});`

Comment: now use underscore :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the accepted answer but uses [_.identity](http://underscorejs.org/#identity) as a predicate for _.pick to pick out the truthy keys:

```
var result = _.keys(_.pick(data, _.identity));
```

Answer (score 2):

In underscore there is function [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick), you can filter data with it and then use [`.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) in order to return array with object keys

```js
var data = {
  first: true, 
  second: false, 
  third: true
};

var result = _.chain(data)
  .pick(function (value) {
    return value;
    // or 
    // return value === true;
    // if you need check exact value
  })
  .keys()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Object.keys() should work for you. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys )

```
var myObject = {first: true, second: false, third: true};
var myKeys = Object.keys(myObject);    //['first', 'second','third']
```

Note that this isn't implemented in older browsers, like IE8. that mdn site above has a polyfill for ya

Comment: Please read the question again. OP wants only the keys having value as `true`.

Comment: @Tushar That's not clear at all. He just states that he want to transform a *boolean dictionary*.